# Cancel subscription through VISA API

Tags: unsubscribe

Currently, I have a VISA debit card which I use to register for some services such as Netflix and Spotify. I wonder if there is a way for me to check all of the services that I am currently subscribing to and cancel some of them through VISA API? I found the Visa Stop Payment Service seems promising, but there are many terms related to parties in the payment process that I do not know clearly.